# Increasing ZoomFactor of a rich text box by a decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to implement a zoom in/out function into a rich text box (entry). I've tried making the zoom increment by '1' but it is too large and makes the text grow to a massive size within 3-4 clicks. Now I'm trying to set the incremental value to '0.5' to increase zoom precision but it gives off the following error:

> CS0266 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

My code:

```
    private void ts_ZoomIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (entry.ZoomFactor < 64.5)
        {
            entry.ZoomFactor = entry.ZoomFactor + 0.5;
        } 
    }

    private void ts_ZoomOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (entry.ZoomFactor > 0.515625)
        {
            entry.ZoomFactor = entry.ZoomFactor + -0.5;
        }
    }
```

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this but I've been stumped with this error for the past half hour and can't find any answers.

Comment: Use `0.5f` instead of `0.5` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the message because evidently entry.ZoomFactor is a float and 0.5 is a double.

The warning message is telling you there is not an implicit cast but there is an explicit cast.

What this means, is that the compiler will not convert 0.5 to a float for you implicity/automatically.  However, you can cast the 0.5 to a float like this:

```
entry.ZoomFactor = entry.ZoomFactor + (float) 0.5;
```

In reality, when the double and float are operated together, the float is automatically converted to a double, but not vice versa.  In reality, the result of entry.ZoomFactor + 0.5 is a double.  So, the following cast would also probably work:

```
entry.ZoomFactor = (float)(entry.ZoomFactor+ 0.5);
```

Better yet, you can avoid the cast as one of the commenters showed and just make the 0.5 naturally a single precision float by calling it 0.5f.

```
entry.ZoomFactor = entry.ZoomFactor + 0.5f;
```

Lastly, since entry.ZoomFactor is a valid l-value, you can probably use the += operator.

```
entry.ZoomFactor += 0.5f;
```